# Creating a file for each URL of a site using Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, web-crawler

I have the following code, which creates a file with the content from a crawled site:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'anemone'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

Anemone.crawl("http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/", :delay => 3) do |anemone|
  anemone.on_pages_like(/http:\/\/www.findbrowsenodes.com\/us\/.+\/[\d]*/) do | page |

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page.url))

    node_id = doc.at_css("#n_info #clipnode").text unless doc.at_css("#n_info #clipnode").nil?
    node_name = doc.at_css("#n_info .node_name").text unless doc.at_css("#n_info .node_name").nil?
    node_url = page.url

    open("filename.txt", "a") do |f|
      f.puts "#{node_id}\t#{node_name}\t#{node_url}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to create not one but various files named `node_id`. I tried this:

```
page.each do |p|
  p.open("#{node_id}.txt", "a") do |f|
    f.puts "#{node_id}\t#{node_name}\t#{node_url}"
  end
end
```

but got this:

```
undefined method `value' for #<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x51c089a name="html"> (NoMethodError)
```

then tried this:

```
page.open("#{node_id}.txt", "a") do |f|
  f.puts "#{node_id}\t#{node_name}\t#{node_url}"
end
```

but got this:

```
private method `open' called for #<Anemone::Page:0x91472e8> (NoMethodError)
```

What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: It’s not quite clear what exactly you are trying to perform. `Anemone::Page` has no `#each` method, hence your code should fail at `page.each` already. It looks like the only change you need to make to your code is `filename.txt` ⇒ `#{node_id}.txt`.

Comment: @mudasobwa if I only do `puts "node_id: #{node_id}, node_name: #{node_name}, node_url: #{node_url}` each page on the site is output. So I think there is an each somewhere in the Anemone code. BUt for some reason, only one file is created. And I need one for EACH url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.open("#{node_id}.txt", "w") do |f|
   f.puts "stuff"
end
```

How you make the assignment to node_id is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit puzzled. I think I understand there was already an `each` statement in the code. But why did it work by only adding `File` and changing `a` to `w`?

Comment: You are essentially asking, "I've never studied the basics of ruby, how come I don't know them?"  There are no shortcuts to learning to program.  You have to read a beginning book--otherwise you can't understand anything, and you just muddle your way through code always unsure of what's going on.  Reading and writing files is basic ruby.

Comment: But basically you required the open-uri module, which allows you to call open() on urls, and treat the returned object as if it was an open filehandle. open() is a private method, which means you cannot specify on object to the left of open(). However, generally that is not the way you open files on your file system (and in fact I did not know you could use open-uri to open files on your file system.). Instead, you use ruby's built in File class and File.open() to open files for writing, and there are several different ways to open files for reading, e.g. `IO.foreach("data.txt") do |line|`

Comment: ...and 'a' means append and 'w' means write.  If you use 'w' to open a file, ruby erases the contents of the file and you start writing at the beginning of the file.  If you use 'a' to open a file, you start writing at the end of the file.